# cnosdb-cli cannot recognize the -p parameter

Tags: database, cnosdb

cnosdb 2.4.0, revision db434d4

I want to use password to connect to CnosDB server.
As "cnosdb-cli help" suggests, I tried to use "-p" to accomplish this.

```
  -p, --password
          Use password to connect to CnosDB server
```

But when I try to do this, I get the error message:

```
❯ ./target/debug/cnosdb-cli -u tester -p 123
error: unrecognized subcommand '123
```

```
./target/debug/cnosdb-cli -u tester -p
CnosDB CLI v2.4.0
Input arguments: CliArgs { subcommand: None, host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "tester", password: true, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, receive_data_encoding: None, send_data_encoding: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false, error_stop: false, process_cli_command: false }
password: 
public ❯ show tables;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010016","error_message":"Auth error: Access denied for user 'tester' (using xxx) username or password invalid"}
```

If you want to reproduce it, you can do this:

```
public ❯ SELECT *
FROM cluster_schema.users;
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_name | is_admin | user_options                                                                   |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root      | true     | {"hash_password":"*****","must_change_password":true,"comment":"system admin"} |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Query took 0.038 seconds.
public ❯ CREATE
USER IF NOT EXISTS tester WITH PASSWORD='123';
Query took 0.867 seconds.
public ❯ SELECT *
FROM cluster_schema.users;
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user_name | is_admin | user_options                                                                   |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root      | true     | {"hash_password":"*****","must_change_password":true,"comment":"system admin"} |
| tester    | false    | {"hash_password":"*****"}                                                      |
+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Query took 0.018 seconds.
```

```
❯ ./target/debug/cnosdb-cli -u tester -p
CnosDB CLI v2.4.0
Input arguments: CliArgs { subcommand: None, host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "tester", password: true, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, receive_data_encoding: None, send_data_encoding: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false, error_stop: false, process_cli_command: false }
password: 
public ❯ show tables;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010016","error_message":"Auth error: Access denied for user 'tester' (using xxx) username or password invalid"}
public ❯ \q
```

```
❯ ./target/debug/cnosdb-cli -u tester -p '123'
error: unrecognized subcommand '123'
```